# Timers won't stop playing sound

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im trying to create an app with playing sound and 4 timers to use If user want to. When timers are finished playing should stop. I got really stuck with this timers here and they are counting down but they don't stop and reset after user stop playback. Also they won't stop the sound if they finished :) their are just counting down..
Could you see what im I doing wrong?
Thanks

My TimerViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var remainingTime: Int = 0
        @Published var totalDuration: Int = 0
    @Published var timerActive: Bool = false

    private var timer: AnyCancellable?
    private var audioPlayerViewModel: AudioPlayerViewModel

    init(audioPlayerViewModel: AudioPlayerViewModel) {
        self.audioPlayerViewModel = audioPlayerViewModel
    }

    func startTimer(duration: Int) {
        remainingTime = duration
        totalDuration = duration
        timerActive = true

        timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.tick()
            }
    }

    private func tick() {
        if remainingTime > 0 {
            remainingTime -= 1
        } else {
            stopTimer()
            stopPlayback()
        }
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timerActive = false
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = nil
    }
    
    func resetTimer() {
            stopTimer()
            remainingTime = 0
        }

    private func stopPlayback() {
        audioPlayerViewModel.audioPlayer?.pause() 
    }
}
```

My PlayerViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation


class AudioPlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var timerViewModel: TimerViewModel?

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    @Published var isPlaying = false
    
    init() {
        if let asset = NSDataAsset(name: "thesound") {
            do {
                self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: asset.data, fileTypeHint: "mp3")
            } catch {
                print("AVAudioPlayer could not be instantiated.", error)
            }
        } else {
            print("Audio file could not be found.")
        }
    }
    
    func playOrPause() {
        guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }
        
        if player.isPlaying {
                    player.pause()
                    isPlaying = false
                    timerViewModel?.stopTimer()
            timerViewModel?.resetTimer()
                } else {
                    player.play()
                    isPlaying = true
                  
                }
    }
    
}
```

TimersView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimersView: View {
    @StateObject private var audioPlayerViewModel = AudioPlayerViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TimerViewModel


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 60) {
                
                ForEach([15, 30, 45, 60] as? [Int] ?? [], id: \.self) { minute in
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.startTimer(duration: minute * 60)
                    }) {
                        if minute == 60 {
                            Text("1 h")
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .whiteTextWithCircularBorder()// Jeśli minuta wynosi 60, wyświetl "1 h"
                        } else {
                            Text("\(minute)")
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .whiteTextWithCircularBorder()// W przeciwnym razie wyświetl normalną liczbę minut
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Text {
    func whiteTextWithCircularBorder() -> some View {
        self
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                
            )
    }
}
```

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var audioPlayerViewModel = AudioPlayerViewModel()
    @StateObject var timerViewModel = TimerViewModel(audioPlayerViewModel: AudioPlayerViewModel())
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
               Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    audioPlayerViewModel.playOrPause()
                }) {
                    Image("Icon-inside")
                    
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    
                }
                Text(audioPlayerViewModel.isPlaying ? "" :  "Push it" ) 
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                Spacer()
               
                if audioPlayerViewModel.isPlaying {
                TimersView(viewModel: timerViewModel) 
                        Text("\(timerViewModel.remainingTime / 60) min")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .padding(.top, 50)
                        .padding(.bottom, 50)
            
                
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

1. I need timers to stop playing sound after countdown is finished.
2. I need to reset and stop timers when user manually turn of sound by pressing the play/pause button

Comment: In your view code you are creating 3 different AudioPlayerViewModel objects, I assume your code will work much better if you only create a single instance. Do you understand the concept of creating an object and having many objects (instances) of the same type? If you start playing using one object then you can’t pause the player using another object, it always needs to be the same one.

Comment: Thanks for responding @JoakimDanielson! 
Ok I think I know what do you mean: AudioPlayerViewModel() - this is creating new objects right?

Comment: Yes it creates a new object

Comment: Ok so AudioPlayerViewModel is only created in AudioPlayerViewModel.swift using class right? and in other files I should use only reference to that right?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of swift and about object oriented programming. Swift basics: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/thebasics

Comment: Yeah im learning it for a year now :) from hackingwithswift.com but im still confused with atState atObservable atObservedObject  ect.

Comment: Also, timers do not tick with high accuracy. Rather than decrementing a count, you should create a `Date` at the start and use `timeIntervalSinceNow` to determine elapsed time

Answer (score 0):

As [@joakim-danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) pointed out, you had created 3 different `AudioPlayerViewModel` objects in all 3 parts of your code which is why your TimerViewModel's `stopPlayback` method didn't work as expected. To fix this, instead of declaring `@StateObject private var audioPlayerViewModel = AudioPlayerViewModel()` on top of the `TimersView` struct, you need to move that line to the top of your view hierarchy to create a single `AudioPlayerViewModel` object that can be shared and accessed by multiple views in your app by adding these lines on top of your view hierarchy:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct yourTimerApp: App {
    @StateObject private var audioPlayerViewModel = AudioPlayerViewModel() // add this line
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(audioPlayerViewModel: audioPlayerViewModel)
                .environmentObject(audioPlayerViewModel) // add this line
        }
    }
}
```

So that you can use the object as an environment object in your `TimersView` struct like this:

```
struct TimersView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var audioPlayerViewModel: AudioPlayerViewModel
    ...
}
```

Since 'ContentView' is a parent view that contains `TimersView` as a child view, you need to initialize `AudioPlayerViewModel` in `ContentView` like this on `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var audioPlayerViewModel: AudioPlayerViewModel
    @StateObject var timerViewModel : TimerViewModel
    
    init(audioPlayerViewModel: AudioPlayerViewModel) {
            _timerViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: TimerViewModel(audioPlayerViewModel: audioPlayerViewModel))
    }
    ...
}
```

On another note, `@StateObject var timerViewModel = TimerViewModel(audioPlayerViewModel: AudioPlayerViewModel())` on `ContentView` was changed to `@StateObject var timerViewModel : TimerViewModel` because the former one creates a new instance of the `AudioPlayerViewModel` object whereas the latter one simply uses the same instance created on top of the view hierarchy.